# AS3 / How do i make my button invisible when i clear the textfield?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a text field and only when I type there is a button to go to the next.
But I also want it to work the other way so when I take away the text in the text field, the button again become invisible.

I have little knowledge with AS3 so if anyone can help me

Thanks.

```
import flash.text.TextField;

var myFont = new Font1();

var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
myFormat.size = 35;
myFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.LEFT;
myFormat.font = myFont.fontName;

var text1:TextField = new TextField();
text1.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
text1.embedFonts = true;

text1.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED; 
text1.text = ""
text1.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
text1.textColor = 0xEC8DAD;
text1.width = 399;
text1.height = 256;
text1.x = 158.95;
text1.y = 307.20;
text1.border = true;
text1.borderColor = 0xDA1C5C;
text1.wordWrap = true;

addChild(text1);

var Button:Next = new Next();
Button.x = 663;
Button.y = 546;
Button.visible = false;
Button.useHandCursor = false;
addChild(Button);

text1.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT,handler);
function handler(event:TextEvent){
    Button.enabled=true
    Button.visible = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Event.CHANGE` event.

```
text1.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,handler);
function handler(event:Event){
    if (text1.text) {
        Button.enabled = true;
        Button.visible = true;
    } else {
        Button.enabled = false;
        Button.visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `ENTER_FRAME` listener.

```
var tf:TextField; //your textfield
var button:Button; //your button

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame); //calls this function EVERY frame

function onEnterFrame(ev:Event):void
{
    if(tf.text == "")
    {
         button.visible = false; //turn your button invsible
    }
    else
    {
         button.visible = true; //turn your button visible
    }
}
```

The advantage being that your `TextField` will get checked once EVERY frame of your swf. So once you remove all text from the textfield, the button will instantly disappear, otherwise if you have at least one character in your TextField, the Button will appear.

Comment: I have everything in one frame (multiple movieClips).